# Remote Desktop into work laptop works when the laptop is on WiFi, but not when it's connected via an ethernet cable

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, remote-desktop

To avoid the hassle of a KVM, I simply use remote desktop to switch between working on my home machine and my work laptop. However, I can only RDP into the laptop when it's connected to WiFi. When I plug in the network cable, it just times out.

I made the sure the cable is good.

The laptop is running Windows 7, and the other machine is running Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you haven't allowed RDP through the firewall on the wired network. Windows firewall rules are specific to the type of network you specified when you first connected to that network - i.e. home, work, public, domain. There are separate rules for each so make sure your wired network is assigned to the correct profile and the correct profile has firewall allows in place for RDP.

Comment: The firewall is actually off, and it's being managed by McAfee. Is there a simple way to test this?

Comment: Simple way would be to turn off the McAfee firewall and see if it works then. I assume you've done basic network diagnostics (ping, etc.) to ensure that's all working on the wired LAN?